# What's the Difference Between Stack Pointer and Frame Pointer in Assembly ARM

Tags: assembly, arm, stack-frame, stack-pointer

I was wondering if someone could please explain to me what's the difference between the Stack Pointer and the Frame Pointer in Assembly ARM

Answer (score 9):

The way I understand it, the SP always points to the next available stack
address(may need to be pre-decremented or pre-incremented first), which
will be used for either pushing data or storing a return address.

The SP can change while the called function is executing, if for example
the function dynamically allocates a block of storage on the stack. Thus
data in the stack frame such as passed parameters and local variables
cannot reliably be referenced through offsets from the SP, since the SP
is not guaranteed to have the same value throughout the execution of
the function.

The FP, OTOH, is guaranteed to have the same value throughout the
execution of the function, so all local data can be accessed via
hard-coded offsets from the FP.  The FP is set to a fixed value within
the stack frame, often just past the last passed argument.

Here is an image I found that may be useful.  You can see that offsets
from FP will always be correct, but offsets from SP will depend on the
size of the dynamic area and thus cannot be hard-coded, in functions that allocate runtime-variable amounts of space in their stack frame (like C99 VLA / alloca).
https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/hosking/502/spim/node23.html.  Functions that *don't* do that can optimize away a frame pointer (optimizing compilers will do that for you when making asm from a higher-level source language like C).

Comment: in arm64 assembly, I saw, at the function start, sp is decremented to hold all the stack variables in the function and fp is also set the the same value as sp. In the function, for stack varible access, sp-relative addressing is used and the arguments were passed through reigsters. So in this case fp and sp is the same (but I guess generally sp can go down and up in the function as the answer says). But I didn't check exactly what happens if stack is used for passing variables..

Answer (score 1):

ARM has generic registers -- they're all the same -- so the designation of particular registers for particular purposes (such as a  stack pointer and frame pointer) is just a convention.

The convention on ARM64 is to use x31 as the stack pointer and x29 as the frame pointer

The convention on ARM32 is to use r13 as the stack pointer.

Comment: *The convention on ARM32 is to use r13 as the stack pointer.* - and r11 as the frame pointer. But as you've mentioned that's a convention used by compiler-makers. When programming in pure assembly a developer can use any register for any purpose they like.